# Instafeed exclude by tag or post

Tags: javascript, instagram-api, instafeedjs

I would like to exclude certain posts from the Instafeed. Either by tag or by some post ID. I know how to apply a filter that only lets pass images specified by tag:

```
  filter: function(image) {
    console.log(image);
    return image.tags.indexOf('thisTagPasses') >= 0;
  }
```

However, I have no idea how to **exclude/skip** certain images. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `filter()` function like so:

```
const excludeItems = (arr, propertyName, filterArr) => {
    return arr.filter(el => filterArr.indexOf(el[propertyName]) !== -1).slice();
}

let instafeedArr = []; // your data

// Filter out all elements where arr.id === 123
let filteredArr = excludeItems(instafeedArr, "id", [123]);

// Filter out all elements where arr.id === 123 or arr.id === 456
let filteredArr = excludeItems(instafeedArr, "id", [123, 456]);
```

Comment: Do I need to put it like filter: function(image){**your code**}?

Comment: And how can I find the arr.id of a certain post? Do you mean the ID from https://www.findinstaid.com/postid?

Comment: And what data do I need to fill in the array at the line with comment "your data"?

Comment: `excludeItems` is a function written in es6 style. I don't know how your array looks like, but I thought it would be an array. If not, rewrite your question to give info about what you actually want. Thanks. @Chiel

Comment: Sorry, I have no Idea what you are talking about. Have you used Instafeed before? The Instafeed object fetches the images, there is no need to use an array to store data. Right?

Comment: No I have not. I have provided a solution to filter out stuff from an array. Provide your code and I might be able to help you. With the code provided, I would be lead to belive that it is about an array.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.